# Java generics not returning the correct value

Tags: java, generics, iterator, linked-list, iterable

I'm implementing a doubly linked list in Java which implement the Iterator class. I have a DoublyLinkedList class with a inner class called DoublyLinkedListIterator to help iterate through the List. (See below).

```
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new DoublyLinkedListIterator();
}

private class DoublyLinkedListIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {
    private Node<E> current;

    private DoublyLinkedListIterator() {
        current = DoublyLinkedList.this.head;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (current != null);
    }

    public Node<E> next() {

        Node<E> ret = null;
        if (hasNext()) {
            ret = current;
            current = current.next();
            return ret;
        }
        else {
            throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException("No next element.");
        }
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Can't remove");
    }
}

}
```

Up above, I am trying to acquire the next value by creating an instance of the iterator, like so...

```
current = iterator.next();
```

(Where current is of the type Node)

For some reason, I keep getting this error:

```
DoublyLinkedList.java:62: error: incompatible types
            current = iterator.next();
                                   ^


required: Node<T>
  found:    T
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class DoublyLinkedList
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you implement `Iterator<E>`, you have to provide a `next()` that returns `E`.  I only see a `next()` that returns `Node<E>`.

Comment: The line in your error is not included in the code you showed.

Answer (score 4):

The `Iterator` interface is defined as

```
public interface Iterator<E> {
    [...]

    E next();

    [...]
}
```

and you're using it as

```
private class DoublyLinkedListIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {
```

but trying to implement it as

```
public Node<E> next() {
```

You shouldn't be returning a `Node<E>`, you should be returning an `E`.

Comment: Either that, or he should be implementing `Iterator<Node<E>>`, depending on what he wants.

Comment: @ajb Right. I will say that it's rare for a linked list to reveal its internals.

Comment: So I'm trying to assign `Node<T> current= iterator.next();` but am still getting the same error. Shouldn't the generic type being returned by next() be a node?

Comment: @user1493543 The return type of `next()` is `E`. What have you used as a type argument for the type parameter `E`? You've used `E`, so it can't be `Node<E>`.

Answer (score 1):

`Iterator<E>` contains a method `E next()`. You haven't declared such a method; you declared `Node<E> next()`.

Try to plug in a concrete type for `E`, if it makes it easier. Imagine you have an `Iterator<String>`. Wouldn't you expect `next()` to return a `String`, not a `Node<String>`?